# FloatingActionButton (FAB) with Android Design support library not elevating

Tags: android, android-support-design

This is my FAB button:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/c"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#fa1d1d" />
```

I'm using the Design support lib:     `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` and testing on Android 6.0.1

The main problem is that regardless of the value I set for `elevation`, it looks the same every time. Here's the screenshot. First button has elevation set to 6, then 12, then 24

Feels like I'm missing something really simple.

[image]

Comment: its not the same. see the shadows for each of them.

Comment: The shadow is not supposed to be dominant visual appearance. If you did it over a white background, it would be more visible.

Comment: Yes, I've tried red on red background now and I can see the difference, although it is very subtle. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct to me, I believe that you're misinterpreting the meaning of the elevation. Elevation only changes the shadow that is drawn under the view. From the docs:

> The elevation of a view (...) determines the visual appearance of its shadow

(http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

If you inspect closely, you'll see that the last button, the shadow is bigger and more "spread out".

Comment: Yes you are correct, thank you. It is working, but very subtle. More visible if I try on the same background as the FAB colour. I think what I was looking for was a way to lift it up a bit more, i.e. make shadow more prominent, but yes logically the higher the object, the more spread out is the shadow. Thanks again.